# Insert fields from one table to another in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a table from which I need to insert some of its data into another table.

I have tables "Provider" and "1_MAIN - Contacts" (I know really bad name, lets just call it "Main" in this discussion). The 2 tables are linked by a column named "Contact_ID". All records in the Provider table have a record in the Main table with a matching "Contact_ID".

The "Providers" table has 4 columns called "geri", "adol", "adult", and "pedi". These fields are datatype `bit` with a default value of `0`.

I have created 4 new columns in "Main" with the same names and want to pull the values from the "Provider" table into the "Main" table.

So basically what I want to accomplish is this:

If a "Main" record has a record in "Provider" then grab the values of the "geri", "adol", "adult", and "pedi" columns from its "Provider" record and copy them into its "Main" record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `UPDATE`, not `INSERT` :

```
UPDATE m
SET geri  = p.geri
  , adol  = p.adol
  , adult = p.adult
  , pedi  = p.pedi
FROM Main m
  JOIN Provider p
    ON p.Contact_ID = m.Contact_ID
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for "INSERT INTO...SELECT".  Something like (you'll need to modify this)

```
Insert Into Main(geri, adol, adult, pedi)
Select p.geri, p.adol, p.adult, p.pedi
 from Provider p
 where p.ProviderID = Main.ProviderID
```

That's rough, because I haven't done it in a while, but it should get you fairly close.

Comment: `UPDATE` we need, not `INSERT` :)